# why are the right answers coming out wrong

Tags: python

```
from random import randint 

correct = 0

for i in range(10):
    n1 = randint(1, 10)
    n2 = randint(1, 10)
    prod = n1 * n2

    ans = input("What's %d times %d? " % (n1, n2))
    if ans == prod:
        print ("That's right -- well done.\n")
        correct = correct + 1
    else:
        print ("No, I'm afraid the answer is %d.\n" % prod)

print ("\nI asked you 10 questions.  You got %d of them right." % correct)
print ("Well done!")
```

What's 1 times 5? 5
No, I'm afraid the answer is 5.

What's 9 times 3? 27
No, I'm afraid the answer is 27.

What's 4 times 1? 4
No, I'm afraid the answer is 4.

Comment: Hey thormose, if you click edit on your post, then select the code and press the `{}` button at the top, it'll indent it and then post it as a proper code block.

Comment: You're comparing numbers with strings. The string `"27"` is not equal to the number `27`.

Comment: This code actually works fine on my computer. I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: What python version are you using Thormouse? You can find out by doing 
`import sys print(sys.version)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the input string into a number:

```
for i in range(10):
    n1 = randint(1, 10)
    n2 = randint(1, 10)
    prod = n1 * n2

    ans = int(input("What's %d times %d? " % (n1, n2)))
    if ans == prod:
        print("That's right -- well done.\n")
        correct += 1
    else:
        print("No, I'm afraid the answer is %d.\n" % prod)
print("\nI asked you 10 questions. You got %d of them right." % correct)
print("Well done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, `ans` are string. so, you should casting like :

```
ans = int(input("What's %d times %d? " % (n1, n2)))
```

Comment: i just try explain why